# Download PDF file from database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have to download most recent uploaded PDF file from MySQL database using PHP. The file can view but while saving it to local folder, instead of saving it as .pdf , it saves .php. and that .php file contains encoded data.

Can anyone suggest how I download/save .pdf file? Code is:

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';

  $sql=mysqli_query($connection,"Select name,content from ekalp where id = (select max(id) from ekalp)"); 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
//$resu=$result['name']; 
$result=$result['content'];
echo $result."<br>";
$filename = $result.'pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  ob_clean();
  ob_flush ();
  @readfile($filename);
 mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/how-display-pdf-browser-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872470/files-sometimes-download-as-php-instead-of-pdf), reproduced here:

> Adding ob_clean(); and flush(); functions before the readfile(); function, could be something worth using, as per what the PHP manual states on the subject.
>
> readfile() http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
>
> ob_clean() http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php
>
> flush() http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php
>
> These functions are not present in your posted code

Comment: i have updated my code above but still not working.

Comment: @user3766182  ok .. good..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $resu holds a uploaded file name. Then why you just don't link to file ??

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';

$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"Select name,content from ekalp where id = (select max(id) from ekalp)"); 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$resu=$result['name'];
?>

<a href="http://YOUR UPLOAD FILE PATH/.<?php echo $resu?>.pdf">Download File </a>
```

Comment: m fetching data from mysql db, so how can i give path ???

Comment: When You Upload PDF File. It Upload / Save to a Destination Folder i.e. http://www.example.com/uploads/files/name.pdf. Isn't It ?

Comment: u are right, but when i uploaded .pdf file, it only saves to db not any folder.

Comment: Yes it's working but whenever m saving file to destination, always need to change its file type and it also shows my .php file name while saving. Is there any trick to make it automatically. Thanks in advace.

Comment: Can You Share Your File Upload Code ?